# Where do some iPhone X ghost text captions come from? (on an Ionic app)

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, iphone-x

We have an Ionic 1 app and we are suffering a lot of issues on iPhone X - just like everyone else.

One of the issues is that on some app screens some floating text captions appear at top left of the screen, like "Search" ("Buscar" in spanish on this screenshot, the small text).

What are those texts and how can we tell iOS to stop showing them?

[image]

Comment: That is the name of app that was opened before your app and you can not tell iOS not to show them.

Comment: @rckoenes so that's a caption of the previous app which is shown just to make you know which app will you activate when you perform the app switch gesture?

Comment: it's a single app test? just previous app? or is it an app history bar? will it show several app names in the last-opened-sort?

Comment: No just the previous app, click on it will also open the app. Swiping will ofcourse also open it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This text is a button to the previous app (X) that was opened when another app (Y) is launched by click on a push notification / url scheme (appY://) or another technique.

Please make sure your view constraints are to the safe area and not to the superview.
[image]

[image]

Comment: sorry, that screen you show... are build options on XCode? Where can I find them? Thank you

Comment: is that from just some Ionic versions? Ionic 1 has that?

Comment: This is a part of the storyboard / xib editor view.
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html

Comment: Ah, okay, not a solution then for Cordova apps